# How to set break points when using jquery chain: obj.appendTo().appendTo().appendTo()?

Tags: jquery

Jquery chain seems easy to read, however, is it possible to set a break point at one of the calls?

```
obj
.appendTo()
.appendTo()
.appendTo()
.doSomething()
.doSomething2();
```

I'm using FireBug in FF.

Comment: I believe not although I could be wrong. each of those functions returns the jQuery object, and that's how it's chaining. I suppose you could somehow not return the jquery object, but that might cause it to error, as the next set of methods won't work after that.

Answer (score 0):

the break point is the `;` or you could even start a new chain without it in modern browser

**nb :** the `.end()` gets back to the initial objectof the chain (if using find() or children in the chain)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.each(function(){debugger;})
```